# Infer the right generic type from a derived class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to infer the type of generic class's attribute.

Example:

```
abstract class A<T> {
  attr: T;
}

class B extends A<number> {
  attr = 1;
}

type Custom = {
  value: string;
};
class C extends A<Custom> {
  value = "1";
}

const a: A<any> = new B();
const b: A<any> = new C();

const instances: A<any>[] = [a, b];

instances.forEach((instance) => {
  // Here I need to set attr with the right type
  const attr = instance.attr;
});
```

How can I do that ?
Probably the problem comes from the use of any when specifying the type of a and b.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your type annotations are making things worse as you are widening the type, not narrowing it. You don't need them, TS already knows the narrowed type:

```
abstract class A<T> {
  attr: T;
}

class B extends A<number> {
  attr = 1;
}

type Custom = {
  value: string;
};
class C extends A<Custom> {
  value = "1";
}

const a = new B();
const b = new C();

const instances = [a, b];

instances.forEach((instance) => {
  const attr = instance.attr; // This is now inferred as `number | Custom`
});
```

Comment: The purpose of my question is to declare those types into a file, and pass them as @Input() attribute of an Angular component, so I need to specify a type for a and b, and maybe i will have thousands of instances within the array, with different attributes types. So I cannot have a union type here ... I am looking for a very generic solution. Maybe my base code is not adapted for that

Comment: You probably will need to now typenarrow if you need to differentiate. That means having if statements to disambiguate the union. Can you edit your original question with the additional calls you need to make, even if they dont compile currently? Then I can help more accurately.